# AudioClip doesn't activate on collision in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple rocket launcher game and I have added the sound of the rocket, which is playing nicely but my other sound, which is supposed to hear it on collision, doesn't activate. The audio file is working as I replaced the rocket launcher sound with it to test it out. Here is the code:

```
    [SerializeField] AudioClip mainEngine;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip dying;

    AudioSource audioSource;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Flying();
        Movement();
    }

    void Flying()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);

            if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
            {
                audioSource.PlayOneShot(mainEngine);
            }


        }

        else
        {
            audioSource.Stop();
        }
    }

 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Start")
        {
            return;
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Finish")
        {
            Debug.Log("Finished");
            return;
        }

        if (!audioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            Debug.Log("Dead"); //debugging if it goes inside the method
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(dying);
        }
        Invoke("ReloadLevel", 1f);
    }
```

And here is the image in the console proving that it goes inside the method.
[image]

Comment: Either way I would remove that `(!audioSource.isPlaying)` check for that case .. otherwise the entire thing might be blocked .. also note that afaik `PlayOneShot` doesn't affect the `isPlaying` anyway so you might be running a lot of concurrent flying sounds

Comment: And the most obvious: is the `dying` clip assigned in the Inspector?

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I added the `(!audiSource.isPlaying)` when I already had this problem. And yes, it is assigned in the Inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What most likely is happening is that the audio is being played, and this code IS being called:

```
Debug.Log("Dead"); //debugging if it goes inside the method
audioSource.PlayOneShot(dying);
```

btw the better way to debug would be to put it after the sound is played, to ensure it gets called...

BUT the sound is instantly stopped by the code within the Flying method, that gets called every frame:

```
void Flying()
{
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
  {
    // Flying stuff
  }
  else
  {
    audioSource.Stop();
  }
}
```

One solution would be to have two Audio Sources, one for the engine sound and one for the death sound. This would allow the Audio Source within the Flying method to only deal with the engine sound effect, and the Audio Source within the OnCollisionEnter to only deal with the death sound effect.

Another solution would be to have a bool for if the player is dead or not. This way, when checking if you should stop the sound within the Flying method, rather than just saying:

```
else
{
  audioSource.Stop();
}
```

You would first check that the player is alive by saying:

```
// Declare the dead bool at the start like you did with: AudioSource audioSource;
// Here we check if we are NOT dead, then stop the engine sound
else if(!dead)
{
  audioSource.Stop();
}
```